# Disposing of Context

Tags: c#, orm, telerik

Hello I have an issue right now with ORM creating too many connections to my databse server. Here is an example:

```
public string AutoCheckPassword {
        get {
            try {
                    Secure360EntitiesModel context = new Secure360EntitiesModel();
                    String DecryptedData = context.GetDecryptedData(AutoCheckPassword_Encrypted);
                    context.Dispose();
                    return DecryptedData;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return "";
            }

        }
        set {

            Secure360EntitiesModel context = new Secure360EntitiesModel();
            AutoCheckPassword_Backup = value;
            AutoCheckPassword_Encrypted = context.GetEncryptedData(value.ToString());
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

`context.GetDecryptedData` is a stored procedure that returns my data unencrypted.
As we can see, I'm calling `context.Dispose()`; but it does not seem to be deleting the connection. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many connection is, "too many"?  How many connections do you *want* to have?  How are you observing how many connections you have?

Comment: We are using a procedure to process several thousand records using a windows service and the number or connections goes up to ~16000 within 10 minutes or so and causes the sql server instance to start denying additional connections. When this happens, the windows service obviously throws several errors and ultimately stops. And yes you are right I have tried using and that did not make a difference

Comment: I been reading this article  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Then you should already know that connections are pooled, and that disposing of a context will not necessarily free the connection that was used, but instead return it to the pool.

Comment: I understand that the connections are placed back in the pool but I cannot figure out why the pool size continues to grow and the existing 'released' connections are not reused. Do we have to explicitly specify a max pool size in the connections string to limit the number of connection and force reuse of the 'released' connections?

Comment: How do you know that your program isn't simply using that many connections?

Comment: ok so lets say the we get one customer that has 10 properties and all these are encrypted. for each one we do the code that I mentioned earlier and call stored procedure to unencrypt my data. foreach property, the application creates one connection. so how do I prevent that from happening or if it must create it how do I get it removed completely from the pool

Comment: You don't do any of those things.  You don't manage the connection pool.  The pool itself will create as many connections as it needs, and it will remove the connections that it doesn't need when they've been idle for a while.  That's what a connection pool is, and this is all discussed in the article that you linked.  Just dispose of all of your contexts, and the pool will automatically handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you should use using statement instead read about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx),
it will also call dispose when exception has been throw.

Also, you can read in msdn on [Managing Connections in Object Services (Entity Framework)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738582(v=vs.90).aspx) (close connection on dispose)

Comment: While he should indeed be using a `using`, that is unlikely to solve the problem he's currently having.

Comment: MSDN says taht EF close the connection on dispose so i assumed he does not call to dispose. using may solve his problem

Comment: No, it will not close the connection when its disposed.

Comment: thank you guys for your answers! Forgot to replied to you guys